# Finding A Digit Pattern For Replacing In Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Imagine we have a time code like this : `00:21:06,200` (our goal)
but in our text we have like this format too : `00:2106,200` or if `00:21x06,200`, x is another number too !
i want to find and to put `:` between 21 and 06 for example or repalce x with `:`.
i tried this way : `(:)+/d{2}`
it finds numbers like this pattern but now i want after finding this pattern numbers, it adds ":" after   second digits and it gonna be like this : `00:21:06,200`. Ty so much :)
My Notepad++ regex isn't so god so i did my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

**Find what:**

```
\b\d\d:\K(\d\d)[x:\d]?(?=\d\d\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d\d:` Match 2 digits and `:`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `(\d\d)` Capture **group 1**, match 2 digits
- `[x:\d]?` Optionally match `x` or `:` or a digit
- `(?=\d\d\b)` Assert 2 digits to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I52TF8/1)

**Replace with:**

```
$1:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Edit->Replace with `Regular expression` selected

`Find what:` (\d\d):?(\d\d):?(\d\d),
`Replace with:` \1:\2:\3,

This looks for 2 digits (i.e. `\d\d`) optionally followed by a colon (i.e. `:?`), followed by another 2 digits followed by an optional colon, followed by another 2 digits and then a comma.

The round brackets commit the digit commit the digit pairs to numbered "registers" which can be recalled in the `Replace with:` using the `\` operator.

Comment: Hi, if we modify your code like this : `(\d\d):?(\d\d):? ` it finds in this ex. `00:2106,200` , this part : `00:21` and puts `:` after 21 and and in `Replace with:` we add `\1:\2` , `\2` puts `:` after second digits and its done ! but do u have an idea for this pattern too ? `00:12345,67` . in this case we want the middle digits (=3) to replace with `:`

Comment: Try `Find what: `(\d\d):?(\d\d)[:0-9]?(\d\d),